# URL rewriting works but corresponding JS calls don't work

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used RewriteRules in htaccess file which works fine. Content of htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    http://mydomain.com/product/display_detail.php?id=$3 [NC,L]
```

URL that I am using is http://mydomain.com/product/some_thing_here1/some_thing_here2/1234

There is a js files which are present in directory http://mydomain.com/product/prod.js. All other content of display_detail.php loads fine. But the content of one of the DIVs has to be changed using JS on load. The load function present in this js file does not work. But if I directly call the URL http://mydomain.com/product/display_detail.php?id=1234, everything works fine.

Paths to js are absolute.

js code which does not work is also pasted below:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$.post("/product/prod_detail.php", { disp: "something"},
       function(responseText, responseStatus){ 
      $("#div_to_be_modified").html(responseText);
});
});
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post js code here which contains ajax call, also post function call.

Comment: modified the question to include js code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your url

```
product/display_detail.php?id=$3
```

but in the desired url

```
product/some_thing_here/1234
```

that is only 2 levels deep after product/ I think this rule should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   product/display_detail.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have corrected the URL structure in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://mydomain.com/product/display_detail.php?id=$3 [NC,L]

Please try to add RewriteCond  before rewrite rule... 
If it is fine please update ticket